# "Dies non juridicum" construction

Tags: legal-latin

I do understand "dies non juridicus", but the phrase "dies non juridicum" seems to be in common use too, witness [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?output=search&q=%22dies%20non%20juridicum%22). How does this construction make sense? Why the neuter "juridicum"? Is it just a grammatical mistake?

Answer (score 2):

When I first saw it, I also assumed it was a mistake. But if so it's a mistake repeated incredibly widely.

So on the assumption that this *is* in fact correct Latin, note that *juridicum* is technically ambiguous. Most often, this is a singular form (masculine accusative or neuter nominative/accusative). But it can also be a genitive plural: "of the judges". This means *dies non juridicum* could also be read as "a day not of the judges".

This usage is not especially common, though; take it as an educated guess at best.

Comment: What would the nom. sg. of gen. pl. *juridicum* be?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I assume *iuridicus*. It sounds more plausible to me to take the short variant of the second declension plural genitive ending than to assume an unattested *iuridex* or similar.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta hm, it seems *iuridicus* for "judge" is even attested in the Digests. That said, I note there is not a single Google hit for "dies non (j/i)uridicorum" and lots of high-quality hits for "dies non juridicus", so I would put this down as a way to salvage the expression as technically correct Latin, but it's likely still an honest mistake.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I agree, this is about salvaging something as technically valid. It often makes for an interesting answer when an honest mistake is salvageable like this.

Comment: Another way of "salvaging" the phrase is by saying it could be a part of a bigger phrase... perhaps something like "dies non juridicum conventum habens"? "dies non juridicum congressum habens"? etc. (I realize these do sound unnatural and unidiomatic.)